# Rails: autolink with ellipsis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the link in text to turn into `<a>` automatically, So I turn to the `autolink` gem.
However, I not only want it to turn into a HTML `<a>`, but also shorten the href displayed.

For example

```
Text: 
Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699459/get-title-content-via-link-in-rails

Returned result
Go to <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699459/get-title-content-via-link-in-rails">stackoverflow.com/questions/8699....</a>
```

That is the `http` is stripped, and the `length` of the text in the `<a>` is stricted.

How can I do that? I think maybe I have to re-invent the wheel again, like:
First find the link, and then strip the `http` and give it a max length. And then generate the `<a>` to replace the original text-kind link in text.

Or I can give up stripping the `http://`, and use CSS's `text-overflow` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem, you can pass a block to `auto_link` which will allow you to truncate the text of the link:

```
post_body = "Welcome to my new blog at http://www.myblog.com/."

auto_link(post_body, :html => { :target => '_blank' }) do |text|
  truncate(text, :length => 15)
end

# => "Welcome to my new blog at <a href=\"http://www.myblog.com/\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.m...</a>."
```

Comment: Wow! This seems pretty amazing. And I think I can also get rid of the `http` prefix at the same time?. But how do I encapsulate this method, so I can use it in my view?